# Question about $\omega$-categoricity

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, order-theory, model-theory

Let $T$ be the theory of linear dense orders with no endpoints and let $\mathcal{L}=\{<,c_0,c_1,\dots\}$ be the language that consists of a binary relation symbol and a countable amount of constant symbols. Given $N\in\mathbb{N}$, I want to show that the $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T_N=T\cup\{c_n<c_{n+1}:0<n<N\}$ is $\omega$-categorical.

I know that $T$ is $\omega$-categorical, so my idea to prove this was the following: Let $\frak{A}$ and $\frak{B}$ be countably infinite models of $T_N$. Let $A$ and $B$ be the universes of $\frak{A}$ and $\frak{B}$, respectively. Define $\tilde{A}=A\setminus\{c_0^{\frak{A}},\dots, c_N^{\frak{A}}\}$ and $\tilde{B}=B\setminus\{c_0^{\frak{B}},\dots, c_N^{\frak{B}}\}$. $(\tilde{A},<)$ and $(\tilde{B},<)$ are both countably infinite models of $T$, so there exists an isomorphism $\psi$ from $(\tilde{A},<)$ to $(\tilde{B},<)$. Finally, define $\phi:A\to B$ by $\phi\restriction_\tilde{A}=\psi$ and $\phi(c_i^{\frak{A}})=c_i^\frak{B}$ for all $i\in\{0,\dots,N\}$. However, I can't seem to show that if $a\in\tilde{A}$ and $a<c_i^{\frak{A}}$, then $\phi(a)<c_i^{\frak{B}}$; so this may not be an isomorphism.

Is my approach correct by any chance? If not, how could I construct an isomorphism between these structures?

Comment: Why do you want to show this?  It certainly is not true--for instance, in a model of $T_N$, the elements $c_n$ for $n>N$ could be in any order, so $T_N$ is not even complete.

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom Thanks for your help! You may want to write an answer instead of a comment, so your answer is more visible.

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't find the fact that useful, but I have been literally been asked to show this specifically.

Comment: Whoever posed the question probably intended to ask for $\omega$-categoricity with respect to the language that has only $c_0,\dots,c_N$ and $<$. At least then the assertion is true.

Comment: Instead of treating your whole $\tilde A$ and $\tilde B$, and then finding that an isomorphism between them doesn't pay any attention to the (interpretations of the) $c$'s, treat separately each of the $N+1$ segments into which the $c$'s divide $\tilde A$ and the corresponding segments of $\tilde B$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for your help! I think that your argument will work perfectly.

Comment: hi @closedrhombus, sorry I missed your comment! when I saw Eric's I deleted mine. were you able to finish using Andreas' hint? (if so I recommend writing it up as a [self-answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)!) if not I am happy to flesh it out for you :)

Comment: Hi @AtticusStonestrom! I was able to finish the proof, but I used what Andreas said and some of what you initially wrote. So if you're willing to write up an answer, feel free to do so.